# Dynamically change parsley rules for a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have a task which I can simple describe: I have a dropdown with, say, 3 positions. And one field.

- If option0 is selected, then no validation for a field required.
- If option1 is selected, then field should be numeric.
- If option2 is selected, then field should match some regex.

How can I achieve this behaviour with `Parsley`?

The only way I found for now is remove a whole parsley, change HTML and then reinit it:

```
$(myDropDown).change(function() {
    $('form').parsley().destroy();

    var input = $(this).parent().find(".my-cool-input");
    //changing input attributes based on selected value

    //reinitialize parsley
    $('form').parsley();
});
```

But here I change global state of whole parsley while I want to change one field validation only.

Another option is writing a custom validator, but I want to reuse standard email and others validation rules and messages, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the field attributes and `trigger('input')` on it.